# Reverse-engineering Java AES-based encryption

Tags: java, c#, encryption, aes

I'm trying to reverse-engineer this Java code in C#, but I keep getting wrong result:

```
public static String GetEncodedToken(String tokenBase64) {
    String str2 = "";
    try {
        byte[] ivBytes = Base64Coder.decode("OSMqNE11fGUoLDg5Mmk1WQ==");
        byte[] keyBytes = Base64Coder.decode("Nm4wMy5nOiM3JSpWfnwzOXFpNzRcfjB5MVNEKl8mWkw=");
        byte[] tokenBytes = Base64Coder.decode(tokenBase64);
        byte[] tokenEncBytes = Encrypt(ivBytes, keyBytes, tokenBytes);
        str2 = URLEncoder.encode(Base64Coder.encode(tokenEncBytes), "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return str2;
}

private static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] ivBytes, byte[] keyBytes, byte[] tokenBytes) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalStateException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    AlgorithmParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
    Key secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    instance.init(1, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec); // 1 = CipherMode.CBC in C#???
    return instance.doFinal(tokenBytes);
}
```

In my understanding the code above in C# translates to the following snippet:

```
public static string GetEncodedToken(string tokenBase64)
{
    var ivBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("OSMqNE11fGUoLDg5Mmk1WQ==");
    var keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("Nm4wMy5nOiM3JSpWfnwzOXFpNzRcfjB5MVNEKl8mWkw=");
    var tokenBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(tokenBase64);
    var tokenEncBytes = Crypt.Encrypt(tokenBytes, keyBytes, ivBytes);
    var tokenEnc = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(tokenEncBytes));

    return tokenEnc;
}

private static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] tokenBytes, byte[] keyBytes, byte[]  ivBytes)
{
    using (var rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged
    {
        Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
        Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
        KeySize = 128,
        BlockSize = 128,
        Key = keyBytes,
        IV = ivBytes
    })
    {
        return rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor()
            .TransformFinalBlock(tokenBytes, 0, tokenBytes.Length);
    }
}
```

However the API I'm trying to log in via C# client tells me the token is wrong :(

Comment: Are the value of `tokenEncBytes` the same (to rule out encoding issues)?

Comment: Your padding is different: in Java you use PKCS5 which operates on 64bit blocks, and in C# you use PKCS7 which supports arbitrary block sizes, but I suppose here it’s the 128bit block size of the cipher. Also you probably should use AesManaged instead of RijndaelManaged, although the former is just a subset of the latter.

Comment: @ixe013 Nope. I use the encoded token for login, but before that I contact the API to get a new token. So yeah every time a new token is encoded

Comment: @ckuri I will definitely try it. I found some examples on a forum (can't find it anymore) where `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` was rewritten using `RijndaelManaged`, so I opted for this class, but you are right, I have to use a proper implementation

Comment: @ckuri the problem is that in C# PKCS5 padding is not defined in PaddingMode enum. So I confirm, that in many examples I found around the Internet people are using PKCS7 in C#:
https://steelmon.wordpress.com/2013/07/01/simple-interoperable-encryption-in-java-and-net/

Comment: @ckuri: The padding is the same. Java's "PKCS5Padding" is really PKCS7Padding.

Comment: It's silly to test the code by supplying it to the API. Just check and see if the Java and C# codes produce the same output for the same input.

Comment: The Base64Coder class is unspecified.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I don't have a full code in Java and what you can see my attempt to de-obfuscate the code. GetEncodedToken function in the snippet I have looks like this:
    `public static String m10510a(String str) {
        String str2 = "";
        try {
            str2 = URLEncoder.encode(rn.m10738a(m10511a(rn.m10741b("OSMqNE11fGUoLDg5Mmk1WQ=="), rn.m10741b("Nm4wMy5nOiM3JSpWfnwzOXFpNzRcfjB5MVNEKl8mWkw="), rn.m10741b(str))), "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return str2;
    }`

Comment: @JamesKPolk I could try to rebuild part of the Java client from partial and obfuscated sources and do some debugging, but converting two relatively simple functions with some help from community seemed to be the fastest option. BTW Base64Coder source code is pretty long and it does the standard base64 encoding / decoding, so if there is something silly that's asking me to add Base64Coder sources

Comment: You don't need the full code,  just test the parts you have shown. I didn't ask you to add the base64 class, I noted it was unspecified. You should have included a link to the javadocs, or at least stated that is was a standard base64 encoder.